# Newbie understanding Messaging.InboundEmailHandler interface

Tags: apex-email-service

I'm writing an Inbound email handler class using Messaging.InboundEmailHandler interface.

I'm following a tutorial [from Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/) but can't find how you find out the structure of an interface? I can't find any specific SFDC docs on Messaging.InboundEmailHandler interface.

I want to understand how to write an email handler myself, without just copy pasting code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to understand how to write and email handler yourself then you should refer to the Apex Developer Guide that goes into this in more detail including the documentation for InboundEmailHandler interface.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_namespace_Messaging.htm

This [developer article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) is also another good reference.